# How to make it difficult to download a video except with player

Tags: php, video, hotlinking

I'm creating a video sharing website like YouTube.  I want to make it so that it is difficult to download the videos to your hard drive.  I want them to still be able to download the videos into F4Player just like any other video.

I am going to make it so that when somneone requests a video using the ID, a PHP script uses the ID to find the real filepath to the video. The PHP script then passes the video, that way no one will find where the video is actually stored.  I also have htaccess set up so that no one can hotlink to my images or videos.

What else can I do?

EDIT:  If it was the only way to get what I need I'd be wiling to make my own player in Java instead of using F4layer, but I strongly prefer using F4Player.

Comment: Once it's on a machine you don't personally control, it's out of your hands. End of story. What you're asking is, "how can I send my content to people without sending it?" Even if you create a proprietary plugin, as suggested below, that plugin could be reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own client side browser plugins, that would handle your proprietary encrypted connection to the video stream.

Comment: I don't want someone to have to download a plugin to use my website.  And besides, I'm going to be using F4Player.  Actually, I could make a player in Java if I really had to.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do this with F4Player but you could try to encrypt the video and decrypt in the player with actionscript, sort of a poor mans DRM.